# React: How to wrap a return value from a hook in a HTML element e.g. span

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a component:

```
<Textbox as="textarea" 
 type="text" 
 placeholder="Variable Types" 
 rows="10" 
 cols="40" 
 maxLength="1000"
 value={variableTypeName} 
 onPaste={e => handlePaster(e)}
 onChange={e => handleChange(e)} 
></Textbox>
```

What I'd like to do is something like this just so I can apply some css to control the padding and line-height in more of a fine grained matter:

```
 value={<span className="VariableTypeName">variableTypeName</span>}
```

But what get renders is: `[object Object]`

When I try to stringify it using `value={JSON.stringify(<span>variableTypeName</span>)}`

I get:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'FiberNode'
> |     property 'stateNode' -> object with constructor 'HTMLDivElement'
> --- property '__reactInternalInstance$oqlpmbh6l7' closes the circle

Any ideas how I can wrap a value with a HTML element?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to insert HTML elements inside the textbox or just the HTML text?

Comment: try logging out the object

Comment: Hi there! I am trying to wrap that value; The value which is rendered in the texarea.

Comment: Yes, but you are wrapping it with a React element. Where you perhaps trying to style the inserted text inside the textbox? I don't think that is doable with inputs. You'd have a better shot with something like a `div` with `contentEditable`